# What non-web-based tools exist to view IIS logs?

Tags: iis, logging

I'm looking for non-web-based tools to view IIS logs.  I've been using [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/logparser/default.mspx) but I was hoping for something with an interface.  It doesn't need to do any fancy reports or charts -- just a list with some search filters is plenty.  I need something lightweight that I can run directly on the web server, preferably without a complex install process.

Answer (score 2):

[VisualLogParser](http://www.codeplex.com/visuallogparser) wraps Log Parser in a GUI. I'm sure there are others as well, but it's fit the bill for me. All the yumminess of Log Parser, with a half-decent interface.

Answer (score 1):

I find that command-line tools are often enough. For example, to list all log entries with a 404 response:

```
findstr "404" logfilename > out.txt
```

Findstr supports regular expressions in the search term and wildcards in the filename, so it is quite flexible for dealing with logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm intrigued why you need more of an "interface" than the command line interface already provided by LogParser? Are you struggling with the SQL-like syntax maybe or is there something else?

LogParser ticks ALL your other requirements. It totally rocks *my* socks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing beats log parser. However, you may want to check out Sawmill & splunk.